# Why is windows XP scanning for malware during update

Tags: windows-xp, windows-update

Stupid Windows XP freezes during update on anti-malware utility update. Is it possible that it tries to scan my disk **during the update**? Killing the process make update continue.

I wanted to reboot and thus decided to install updates that would require a reboot too. After a while, updating was still not complete and I had to manually kill process. Why that stupid behaviour? Why not to scan in background, like all other AV software?

Is there a way to disable this behaviour?

Answer (score 5):

It does this because if it didn't, the update may break your computer.

Picture your nice XP computer compromised. Some core software modules have been infected and they change the way your computer is being run. Now you run an update. These infected modules are moved around, and no longer have the proper execution paths. The hooks that the malware used are now no longer pointing to any valid code. Your computer is now a very big and noisy paperweight.

This is not a theoretical. It did happen. And people blamed Microsoft. The computer went from a working (though infested) machine to one that wouldn't boot. Peopel blamed Microsoft, since they were the trigger that caused them to break. Microsoft knew they needed to fix this, and created a piece of software that tried to clean malware before installing any update.

As far as timing; it really needs to be done before an update. An in the background scan may allow something to be installed (and broken) before a proper scan.

If it bothers you, maybe you can meditate on these things:

1. it normally only takes any real time if you have malware, and in this case you really do want it to run and clean.
2. if you did have malware, and the update did cause your machine to not boot, you would be spending a lot more time reinstalling Windows and getting your apps to work. And at that point, probably wishing Microsoft did do something to prevent this bad cycle.

In short, it works as designed, and though it takes some time, you really do want this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's precisely what it does. Every month, Microsoft releases an updated version of its Malicious Software Removal Tool, which works like a mini virus scanner, searching for a small set of specific, pervasive, and dangerous malware. It performs a short, one-time scan when the update is "installed". It is just a scan, and does not actually install anything permanent.

The reason Microsoft does this is to provide some basic layer of automatic protection for users who do not have a virus scanner.  It's possible to deselect the update if you install updates manually, but it will keep coming back every month. I do not believe there's a way to categorically deny the MSRT forever, but I may be wrong.